# Javascript remove character and return string

Tags: javascript

substr and substring not changing the original value. I want to change the original value and want to return a string after removing the character.

```js
var String_text =  'Hello world!';
alert(String_text.substr(4,1));
```

Expected Output

> Hell world!

Comment: Poor question :(

Comment: text.slice(0,4)+text.slice(5). Try this

Answer (score 0):

You can use replace

```js
var String_text =  'Hello world!';
alert(String_text.replace('o',''));
```